# encrypt and decrypt from php to c++

Tags: php, c++, web-services, encryption

I need a way to encrypt and decrypt from PHP to C++ and vise versa.

For example, I need to send an encrypted ID from a PHP web service to a C++ application and then decrypt it in C++ and vise versa.

Another question: is there any way to secure data from and to a web service?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use a standard encryption algorithm on both ends, and you should be fine.

Comment: Have you tried throwing SSL at the problem?

Comment: PHP is written in C++. Go get the source code for the PHP method you are using and implement it in you C++ application, that way no only are you using the same algorithm at both ends, you are using the same code.

Comment: @KerrekSB The algorithm is rarely the problem. It's incorrect use of the algorithm that breaks systems. When a beginner designs a protocol, it's practically guaranteed to be totally broken.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on what sort of threats you need to defend and what your resources are.
And as one can imply from your question you are not very knowledgeable in the field of cryptography you should consider using well known solution instead of trying to invent and/or implement some cryptographic solution by yourself.
There are many subtle things in building watertight cryptographic system that it's not advisable to build one without thorough prior study.

If you want to secure against someone eavesdropping or changing the data while it's transmitted over the network consider using SSL/TLS to secure the whole network connection.
On C side you may use any HTTP library that would allow HTTPS connections. I may recommend you the [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). If you are already  using some framework like Qt there may be API to make that HTTPS request.
On PHP side you would need to setup your server to serve this script (or the whole service) through https. Refer to your server documentation to see how it's done.

For the server-side you would need a certificate. If you have only your own software to connect to that https server you will be well enough with a certificate from your own self-signed CA. Creating one would be a bit different on Windows and POSIX systems but there's plenty of HowTos on the Internet. Be sure to set this CA certificate to be the only trusted one when you make the request in your C code. If you would also like other software like general-purpose browsers to connect to your https service you'll have to buy an SSL certificate from any recognized CA.

If instead you would like to use some symmetric cipher on the both sides, that would pose serious question on things like key exchange, known plaintext attacks, message authentication and other. I can advise you there but for that the knowledge of nature and limitations of the system you are about to build would be essential.